# При постоянной проверки пинга интернет зависает

Tags: c#

```
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply pingReply = ping.Send("95.213.255.83");
    Console.WriteLine(pingReply.RoundtripTime); //время ответа
    Console.WriteLine(pingReply.Status);        //статус
    Console.WriteLine(pingReply.Address);       //IP
    Console.ReadKey(true);
```

У меня есть кнопка с которой я проверяю пинг игрового сервера (любого мне кажется)
Если я нажимаю больше 190 раз, интернет зависает полностью и пинг + вообще ни один сайт не отвечает/не открывается.

Помогите, кто может

Comment: 190 раз подряд? Зачем? Не открывается с компьютера? Или блочится на роутере? tracert что показывает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первое, что я бы рекомендовал в данном случае - это использовать один из блоков:

- [`try-catch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch)
- [`try-catch-finally`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch-finally)

Это обезопасит от непредвиденных ситуаций, к примеру когда вывалится исключение.

Второе, что я бы посоветовал, так это использование асинхронной версии метода `Send`. Я не уверен, что именно через 190 попыток должно все так критично крошиться, но осмелюсь предложить данное исправление. А лучше всего установить тайм-аут (дольше, чем тайм-аут для команды `Ping` по умолчанию), а затем вызвать `SendAsyncCancel`, чтобы отменить все ожидающие асинхронные запросы перед отправкой `SendAsync`. С классом `Ping` и его методами и свойствами можно ознакомиться здесь: [класс Ping пространства имен `System.Net.NetworkInformation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx) Также, настоятельно рекомендую ознакомиться с разделом *Комментарии* данной статьи. Не будет лишним и это: [The Internet Engineering Task Force](http://www.ietf.org/)

Также, я не советую создавать множество экземпляров типа:

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
```

Если данный блок кода зациклен, то вынесите переменную `ping` из этого блока и пользуйтесь лишь одним экземпляром. Где-то натыкался на статью, в которой была подобная проблема и сопровождалась утечкой памяти.

Comment: Я столько мучился и искал ответа.. Но и сейчас у меня недопонимания как работает это асинхронное соединение. Я конечно использую его и удивляюсь. Реально вроде все работает. Сколько я не нажимаю обновить и показать пинг сервера все показывает. Правда с очень маленькой задержкой, раньше практически задержки не было. 

Спасибо большое за совет. 

Так же мне нужно было раньше вывести информацию с 1000 серверов и показать все в DataGrid, но у меня не получалось по этой причине(инет наглухо зависал после 180 сервера или если быстро подключаться, то после 150 даже. В итоге отложил эту функцию.